# mysql logical ranking based on score

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.6, rank

I have a table like this that keeps a total score of a history exam for students.

```
+----+---------------+-------+---------+-
| id | name          | history |  rank  | 
+----+---------------+-------+---------+-
|  1 | yngiid        |    97   |        | 
|  2 | viyrp         |   217   |        | 
|  3 | pae           |   599   |        | 
|  4 | spohl         |   284   |        | 
|  5 | shl           |   295   |        | 
|  6 | okeer         |    73   |        | 
|  7 | jmaany        |   657   |        | 
|  8 | hxt           |    80   |        | 
|  9 | yanier        |   599   |        | 
+----+---------------+-------+----------+-
```

The history field as you can see contains the total score the student . Now, I would like to rank the students by their scores as in, the higher the points the lower the rank.

#### Expected output.

```
+----+---------------+-------+----------+-
| id | name          | history |  rank  | 
+----+---------------+-------+----------+-
|  7 | jmaany        |   657   |   1    | 
|  3 | pae           |   599   |   2    | 
|  9 | yanier        |   599   |   2    | 
|  5 | shl           |   295   |   3    | 
|  4 | spohl         |   284   |   4    | 
|  2 | viyrp         |   217   |   5    |         
|  1 | yngiid        |    97   |   6    | 
|  8 | hxt           |    80   |   7    |     
|  6 | okeer         |    73   |   8    | 
+----+---------------+---------+--------+-
```

I have looked at [answers in stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3333665/rank-function-in-mysql?rq=1)  but the answers have some issues like:

In the below example, methods will increment the rank when users have the same score, as in the example of `pae` and `yanier`

```
|  7 | jmaany        |   657   |   1    | 
|  3 | pae           |   599   |   2    | 
|  9 | yanier        |   599   |   3    | # shold be 2 bc pae&yanier have equal points
|  5 | shl           |   295   |   4    |
```

Other solution will fix the above problem but skip the *the next* rank number if scores are the same example:

```
|  7 | jmaany        |   657   |   1    | 
|  3 | pae           |   599   |   2    | 
|  9 | yanier        |   599   |   2    | 
|  5 | shl           |   295   |   4    | # should be 3 b/c .. logic
```

These are just some of the problems, so I am wandering if there is a solution to output the expected result.

Here is a sample table dump if it helps.

```
create table `test` (
    `id` int (11),
    `name` varchar (765),
    `history` int (11),
    `rank` int (11)
); 
insert into `test` (`id`, `name`, `history`, `rank`) values('1','yngiid','97',NULL);
insert into `test` (`id`, `name`, `history`, `rank`) values('2','viyrp','217',NULL);
insert into `test` (`id`, `name`, `history`, `rank`) values('3','pae','599',NULL);
insert into `test` (`id`, `name`, `history`, `rank`) values('4','spohl','284',NULL);
insert into `test` (`id`, `name`, `history`, `rank`) values('5','shl','295',NULL);
insert into `test` (`id`, `name`, `history`, `rank`) values('6','okeer','73',NULL);
insert into `test` (`id`, `name`, `history`, `rank`) values('7','jmaany','657',NULL);
insert into `test` (`id`, `name`, `history`, `rank`) values('8','hxt','80',NULL);
insert into `test` (`id`, `name`, `history`, `rank`) values('9','yanier','599',NULL);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT
    T1.id,
    T1.`name`,
    T1.history,
    T2.rank
FROM
    test T1
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT
        history,
        (@v_id := @v_Id + 1) AS rank
    FROM
        (
            SELECT DISTINCT
                history
            FROM
                test
            ORDER BY
                history DESC
        ) t,
        (SELECT @v_id := 0) r
) T2 ON T1.history = T2.history
ORDER BY
    history DESC
```

with result as:

```
7   jmaany  657 1
3   pae     599 2
9   yanier  599 2
5   shl     295 3
4   spohl   284 4
2   viyrp   217 5
1   yngiid  97  6
8   hxt     80  7
6   okeer   73  8
```

Comment: Saved my day! Nice answer.